# Burninate the [godaddy] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

First off, [godaddy](/questions/tagged/godaddy) has 903 questions tagged with it. <s>[godaddy-economy-hosting](/questions/tagged/godaddy-economy-hosting) has 15.</s> (*no longer true, burninated*)

**EDIT:** we're at under 100 questions with godaddy tagged.

GoDaddy is a platform for hosting, and these askers seem to think that tagging their questions with their service provider, when it doesn't make too much of a difference, will in some way solicit more answers. (well, technically it *does* apparently, because more baffled people come from Google for oft unrelated questions just because of "godaddy" in the title...)

GoDaddy is quite literally just shared VPS hosting, same as any other hosting, running on an IIS cluster if Windows or apache if Linux. They are often the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because these users are pretty much assuming their sloppy coding can't be their fault and assume it is the hosting provider's fault.

The majority of these questions* simply casually mention their hosting provider at the start of the question:

> I'm [hosting|deploying] a [insert app/technology name] [project|site] on [hosting provider]

While this is fine and dandy to mention, it doesn't really tell us much of anything extra to mention the hosting provider, and it certainly doesn't make sense to tag it as such, unless GoDaddy were wishing to outsource their support or something. We can't magically fix a hosting problem with software solutions just because we know who your plumber is, or anything. We certainly wont be following that plumber's tags on SO to see a wide range of unrelated things they haven't done, either.

---

There are also a few questions which are effectively just godaddy support, namely:

- [How to access the php.ini file in godaddy shared hosting linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140917)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118746

  - Should be retagged [php](/questions/tagged/php), and maybe(?)[file-upload](/questions/tagged/file-upload), though that tag is also really broad

---

My request is this:

1. <s>Burninate the [godaddy-economy-hosting](/questions/tagged/godaddy-economy-hosting) tag completely and immediately.</s> DONE.
2. Burninate the [godaddy](/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag.
3. Close questions which are solely tagged with [godaddy](/questions/tagged/godaddy) (I have no idea how to search for this. Anyone know?) as off-topic.

Anyone else agree? If not, why?

<sub>* Sample of 80. I also came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128369)</sub>

---

**EDIT 2:**

It seems the vast majority of the remaining GoDaddy questions are pretty much GoDaddy tech support (And if you look in the tag top users, there's [a godaddy employee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316552/mike-godaddy), too). There is also a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570722/how-does-the-base-url-work-godaddy-magento) I just flagged, which is clearly by a novice user, and would have probably been titled by me as "Magento base_url structure" over on Magento.SE. So many of these questions are either purely off-topic (*how can i has teh codes on my host?*), or have fluff in them about their web hosts.

When we are done with this tag, can we please have it blacklisted along with other web hosting/DNS hosting guys? Because everything that uses these tags is either off topic for SO, or is incorrectly using the tag.

As an addendum, due to Charles' comment, I have yet to find any questions about the godaddy API so far.

Comment: I don't think we should kill the tag completely.. it may have value in some cases.

Comment: Yes, definitely. If we keep Go Daddy tags, then requests for tags for other hosts would be reasonable, and _that_ would be a huge mess.

Comment: @0A0D can you provide an example of an instance where it would be a valid tag?

Comment: Devils advocate:  does this mean that the [tag:heroku], [tag:azure], [tag:azure-web-sites] and other similar tags should be removed as well?  How are those tags different from [tag:godaddy]?

Comment: They're different because they provide APIs, platforms, development technology, deployment bits, and other *development-relevant* things.  While godaddy *does* have some API bits (for resellers, apparently), most of the questions with the tag are *not* used for that API.  The common use is "oh, I'm hosted there," which is irrelevant.  Questions about the API bits should be retagged, then the tag nuked from orbit.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: here is an example that is localized to godaddy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128213/mysql-connection-issues

Comment: @charles so burninate [tag:godaddy] and then create a [tag:godaddy-api] tag for the edge cases?

Comment: @Hiroto, bingo.  Unfortunately this is going to have to be a manual process, with a queue of 900+ questions...

Comment: I'm working on the [tag:godaddy] questions.

Comment: working on de-localizing the godaddy tagged questions that have noise in them now.

Comment: Solely godaddy questions: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/113482/select-all-questions-with-only-a-specific-tag?Tag=godaddy (enter godaddy as the parameter)

Comment: Godaddy's back: 1004 questions as I type.  Almost all are still pretty much tech support issues, or are general and not specific to Godaddy.

Comment: @quantas I'll ping a dev later and ask about this

Comment: I came here to post the same request. I am on a personal mission to remove `godaddy` tags from questions where it is clearly irrelevant. There are a lot of GoDaddy tech support questions though, where the tag is relevant even though the question is inappropriate for SO. Many of those can probably be closed as "general software" or "recommending a library or tool". Still, burninating the tag won't stop the questions. Maybe it makes sense to keep the tag, so SO knows what questions to automatically close. ;)

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228693/blacklist-godaddy-tag-and-rename-to-godaddy-api?lq=1